# React / Next.js Change image src onLoad

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What is right way to add loader before image source is loaded in React?

This example with onLoad function does not work properly. I tried with the state but it doesn't work well either because the state changes after loading the first image so it doesn't work for all images.

Any help?

```
{posts.map( post => (
    <Card key={post.id}  id={post.id}>
      <Link href={ `/blog/${ post.slug }` }>

       <Image src={'/loading.gif'} onLoad(e => e.target.src={post.featured_image.post-crop}) unsized />

       <p>{post.title}</p>
     </Link>
    </Card>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the source of image in the state.

Example

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const loadingUrl = "https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif"

const imageUrl = "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"

const Image = ({src: _src}) => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(loadingUrl)

  const onLoad = () => {
    if(src === loadingUrl) {
      const timeout = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000)
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        setSrc(_src);
      }, timeout);
    }
  }

  return <img width="100" src={src} onLoad={onLoad}/>
}

const data = Array(3).fill(0).map(pr => ({imageSrc: imageUrl}))

const App = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(data);

  return <div>
    {posts.map((post, index) => <Image key={index} src={post.imageSrc}/>)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hm ok, but this is ok example for one image. I have list of posts and each post has its own image that needs to be loaded.

Comment: Updated example, the idea is still the same, source of the image must be stored in the state

Answer (score 0):

For this, it might be best to create your own custom loadable image component. The component will consist of a base64 encoded image readily available as the src for a loading spinner (so this does not have to load too... see the codesandbox at the bottom) and will handle the entirety of loading an image. You can also display error image, or handle retries etc within a single component.

Something like this (this is standard react, but you can use this concept)

```
const LoadableImage = (props) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  //you can always store errors to show an error image if it could not be found etc
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const loadingImgStyle = {
    display: loaded ? "none" : undefined
  };

  const displayImgStyle = {
    display: loaded ? undefined : "none"
  };

  return (
    <div width={props.width} height={props.height}>
      <img src={Spinner} style={loadingImgStyle} alt={"Loading"} />
      <img
        src={props.src}
        width={props.width}
        height={props.height}
        alt="loadable"
        style={displayImgStyle}
        onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadableImage;
```

now you can map your images and each one will control its own state

```
{posts.map( post => (
    <Card key={post.id}  id={post.id}>
      <Link href={ `/blog/${ post.slug }` }>
       <LoadableImage src={post.featured_image.post-crop}/>
       <p>{post.title}</p>
     </Link>
    </Card>
))}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-vaughan-c38mp?file=/src/LoadableImage.js:75-820)